# The absolute Galois group of a finite field is strongly complete

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, profinite-groups

Let $k$ be a finite field. 
I am trying to prove that the absolute Galois group of $k$, i.e., $G = \operatorname{Gal}(\bar{k} / k)$ where $\bar{k}$ is an algebraic closure of $k$, is strongly complete, i.e., each subgroup $H$ of $G$ of finite index is open in the Krull topology of $G$.

Since $G$ is a disjoint union of finitely many left (or right) cosets of $H$, and since the left (or right) multiplication for a fixed element of $G$ is an homeomorphism, I found that $H$ is open if and only if it is closed. Moreover, from the Galois correspondence I know that $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar{k}/\bar{k}^H) = \operatorname{cl}(H)$, where $\bar{k}^H$ is the subfield of $\bar{k}$ fixed by $H$ and $\operatorname{cl}(H)$ is the topological closure of $H$.

However, I can find no way to prove that $H = \operatorname{cl}(H)$.
Probably I am missing something trivial.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: This may not be true for a general field $k$, so you might have use the fact that for finite fields
$$\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)\cong\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}=\varprojlim_n\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$
(generated by Frobenius)

Comment: @curious, to me this looks like the right approach. I’d attack the problem by hoping to show that a subgroup of $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ of index $n$ intersects $\mathbb Z$ itself in a (the!) subgroup of index $n$.

Comment: @Marvolo : I now updated my answer, hopefully you have enough details to finish. Feel free to ask any questions in the comments.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I have not concluded yet.
Put $H^\prime = \langle \sigma_k^n \rangle$ and let $F$ be the fixed field of $H^\prime$.
Then $F$ is the splitting field of $x^{q^n}-x$, where $q=|k|$, so that $|F| = q^n$ and $[F:k] = n$.
Let $E$ be the fixed field of $\mbox{cl}(H)$.
From your Hint we have that $G / \mbox{cl}(H)$ is cyclic, of order less than $n$, since $\sigma_k^n \in H$ implies
$\sigma_k^n \in \mbox{cl}(H)$. Thus $|G / \mbox{cl}(H)| = [E:k]\leq n$. ...

Comment: ... But from this I do not get information, since $E$ is a subfield of $F$, so it is right that $[E:k]\leq [F:k]$ (I am trying to prove $E=F$).

Comment: @Marvolo : Let me put it like this. The subgroup $H' =\langle \sigma_k^n \rangle$ corresponds to the subfield $F$, and since $F/k$ is Galois (because it is a splitting field of a separable polynomial, as you noticed), the subgroup $H'$ is *normal* in $G$. Now the subgroups $H' \le H \le G$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $G/H'$, which is the Galois group of the extension $F/k$ (in particular, a *finite* cyclic group).

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva when you say that "$H^\prime$ corresponds to $F$", you are using the Galois correspondence, but it holds only for closed subgroups, so $H^\prime$ is closed? Anyway, if $gH^\prime$ is a generator of $G/H^\prime$, then $H/H^\prime$ is generated by $g^d H^\prime$, where $d \mid n$. So $H$ is a disjoint union of finitely many cosets of $H^\prime$. Hence, actually, if I prove that $H^\prime$ is closed, then $H$ is closed.

Comment: @Marvolo : $H'$ is normal since $G$ is abelian. Since $G$ is the inverse limit of the projections $G \to G/\langle \sigma_k^n \rangle \simeq \mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$, the projection $G \to G/H'$ is continuous, so $H'$ is closed. I guess I looked at it the wrong way around the first time, but this is really the first step after my comment, otherwise you can't do much.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Note that in the sense you interpret $\langle \sigma_k^n\rangle$, $G/\langle \sigma_k\rangle$ is not the trivial group -not every element in $G$ is a power of $\sigma_k$-. Furthermore, no $G/\langle \sigma_k^n\rangle$ is finite.

Comment: @Josué Tonelli-Cueto : Arghh. Then I guess I induced OP in mistakes. You're right. At least I tried! I apologize to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting, let me note that what you have asked is just a particular case of the Nikolov-Segal's theorem ([On finitely generated profinite groups I](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604399v1) and [II](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604400v1)) that states that in a finitely generated profinite group, every subgroup of finite index is open. This was a generalization of a previous result by Serre for finitely generated pro-$p$ groups.

So this means that the important think is that the profinite group $G$ that we are considering is finitely generated. In particular, it is procyclic so thinks get even easier.

The first we should note is that
$$G^n=\{g^n\,|\,g\in G\}$$
is a closed subgroup of $G$ since it is the image of $G$ under the continuous homomorphism of groups $g\mapsto g^n$. Furthermore, in our considered case --the procylic group generated by the Fröbenius automorphism--, we can easily see that
$$|G:G^n|=n$$
Now, given a subgroup $H$ of $G$ of finite index $n$, we should have
$$G^n\leq H$$
since the $n$-th power of every element of $G$ is the identity in the quotient $G/H$. But $G^n$ and $H$ have the same index, so they must be equal and therefore $H$ is closed as desired.

Comment: You wrote "every subgroup of finite index in finite", you probably meant open!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes, thank you for the correction ;)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes. It is profinite for being the quotient by a closed subgroup, it is procyclic for being generated by the continuous image of the generator $\overline{\sigma}$ and it is finite because $\overline{\sigma}^n=\overline{1}$. Thus it is a finite cyclic group.

Comment: I must say, up to now I stil don't see why the image of $G$ by the $n^{\text{th}}$ power map is closed. Is this a topological group result or something?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Let $p:G\times G\rightarrow G$ be the group operation, continuous by hypothesis, then $g\mapsto g^n=p(g,p(g,p(g,\ldots,p(g,g))\ldots )))$ is continuous -easy to check by induction-. Since $G$ is compact, so it is $G^n$ the continuous image of $G$ and, due to the fact that $G$ is Hausdorff, $G^n$ must be closed.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't know $G$ was compact Hausdorff. You could've just mentioned that! But thanks

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva You are right, sometimes I give too detailed answers. My fault.

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Josué Tonelli-Cueto : Nah, actually it's okay, you couldn't guess what I wasn't knowing. I was just saying since my problem with this question is the non-understanding of the properties of the group $G$, it would've been sufficient to state that $G$ satisfies general things :P