# Are normal subgroups of finite index in an absolute Galois groups open?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group. It is known that open normal subgroups of $G$ have finite index, but in general not every normal subgroup of finite index is open (see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profinite+group#examples for a counterexample). This last fact is true if the profinite group is (topologically) finitely generated (this is a theorem of Nikolov–Segal).

Let now $K$ be a field. A theorem about the "inverse Galois problem" states that for every profinite group $G$ there are fields $K\subseteq L\subseteq F$ such that $Gal(F/L)\cong G$. This means that also for general Galois groups, it is not true that every normal subgroup of finite index is open.

My question is: could this be always true for absolute Galois groups, i.e. for Galois groups of extensions $\bar{K}/K$ with $K$ field and $\bar{K}$ the separable closure of $K$?

My question is justified by a sentence I found in Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" where, at the beginning of the appendix B.2, it is written

*"Let $G_{\bar{K}/K}$ be the Galois group of $\bar{K}/K$. (...) Thus $G_{\bar{K}/K}$ is a profinite group, i.e. an inverse limit of finite groups. As such, it comes equipped with a topology in which a **basis of open sets** around the identity consists of the **collection of normal subgroups having finite index** in $G_{\bar{K}/K}$"*.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{Q}$ is a counterexample: https://mathoverflow.net/a/82178/159786

Comment: But it's true for finite fields: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013555/688699

Comment: I'm confused with Silverman since *any* group can be equipped with the profinite topology defined the same way. Maybe the issue is that he's just working with this topology on the absolute Galois group instead of the Krull topology. See the last paragraph on page 7 of these notes: https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2015fa/LectureNotes23.pdf

Comment: Actually after looking at those MIT notes (Thm 23.22), I think Silverman means the Krull topology but has just characterized it wrongly.

Comment: Thankyou for the hint to look at Milne notes. Indeed, I was very confused by Silvermann's sentence: I know that any group can be endowed with a topology such that a base of open neighborhoods of the identity  is made by open normal subgroups, but it doesn't seem the more natural topology in this setting. Another confusing issue is that Silvermann really uses his definition, when after a few lines he says that the action of the Galois group on a module is continous if and only if the stabilizers have *finite index*, whereas we usually have to require that they are open.

Comment: Edit: I mean, I know that any group can be endowed with a topology such that a base of open neighborhoods of the identity is made by normal subgroups of finite index.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph you cited from Silverman is referring to the following fact: In a profinite group, the collection of open normal subgroups form a base of neighborhoods of the identity. (Lemma 1-17, p.29 in *Fourier Analysis on Number Fields*).

Here on a Galois group, Silverman considers the Krull topology. Concerning the stabilizer, I think he should require the stabilizer to be open rather than just of finite index.